# SQL Error - VALUES keyword missing

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am getting the following error and I am not sure why

```
  INSERT INTO
        PRODUCT_TYPE, PANELIST_PROD_TYPE_DETAIL
             (TYPE_DESC, PRODUCT_TYPE_NUM)
        VALUES('JR' , 0)
```

Error

> *Missing VALUES keyword*

I am not sure why I am getting this error as `VALUES` is in the SQL statement.

`TYPE_DESC` is in table `PRODUCT_TYPE` whereas `PRODUCT_TYPE_NUM` is in table `PANELIST_PROD_TYPE_DETAIL`.

Can someone please tell me what is wrong with my SQL statement?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to insert to each table individually like this:

```
INSERT into PRODUCT_TYPE(TYPE_DESC) VALUES('JR');
INSERT INTO PANELIST_PROD_TYPE_DETAIL(PRODUCT_TYPE_NUM) VALUES(0);
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to create one insert statement per table:

```
INSERT into PRODUCT_TYPE(TYPE_DESC) VALUES('JR');

INSERT into PANELIST_PROD_TYPE_DETAIL (PRODUCT_TYPE_NUM) VALUES(0);
```